# How to retrieve data from Oracle table group by hour

Tags: oracle

Problem Statement: My query return data which have `created_date` which mean when the record has been created. This column is a date type which contain hours in the result.

I want to publish the data grouped by date with hourly distribution.

Sample Result:

[image]

Currently I am using the following query get the distribution on day basis,

```
SELECT TRUNC(CREATED_DATE),COUNT(*) FROM IMAGE_HISTORY
WHERE CREATED_DATE >= SYSDATE-7
GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATED_DATE)
ORDER BY TRUNC(CREATED_DATE) ASC
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TRUNC(CREATED_DATE, 'HH')` to truncate everithing after hours like so:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(CREATED_DATE, 'HH'),COUNT(*) FROM IMAGE_HISTORY
WHERE CREATED_DATE >= SYSDATE-7
GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATED_DATE, 'HH')
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are after is a group by hour of day (e.g. maximum of 24 rows in the result), then use `TO_CHAR` instead of `TRUNC`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CREATED_DATE, 'HH24'),COUNT(*) 
  FROM IMAGE_HISTORY
 WHERE CREATED_DATE >= SYSDATE-7
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(CREATED_DATE, 'HH24')
 ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

`TO_CHAR` formats a string using the pattern specified, so if you specify *only* hours (`HH` or `HH24`), that's all you will get. No day, just the hour (as a string).

But if you're after a record for every day-hour pair (7*24 = 168 rows), then `TRUNC(CREATED_DATE,'HH')` is correct. `TRUNC` zeros out the time portion lower than the specified mask and returns the result as a date. Think of it as "round down to nearest X". I suppose you could also do `TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')` but the string is less desirable than a real date, so the `TRUNC` method is preferred if you want the day preserved.